# Dropdown content displayed to the right column in masonry layout

Tags: html, css, dropdown, masonry

I'm using masonry layout to get two columns with different height elements in each of them. In the first column I have a dropdown element, with 3 entries. When I hover over the dropdown, the content is displayed in the second column, not if the first one. I think this is because of the masonry layout I'm using. How can I update the code to make the dropdown display the content in the first column?

Here is the code:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
    width: 100%;
  display: none;

  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.masonry-wrapper {
    column-count: 2;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="masonry-wrapper">

<div class="item">
    <h1> Left item </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
        <h1> Dropdown </h1>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="item">
    <h1> Right item </h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you want, but it does what you're asking for.  Removed "position: absolute;" and changed "display: block;" to "display: inline-block;".

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
    width: 100%;
  display: none;

  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.masonry-wrapper {
    column-count: 2;
    width: 100%;
}

.right-item {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="masonry-wrapper">

  <div class="dropdown">
        <h1> Dropdown </h1>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="right-item">
    <h1> Right item </h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your response. It really solves the issue for 2 entires. But my real problem was about 3 entries. Didn't know if there would be any difference between these two cases, but as seems there is. Your solution solves the two item case, but still not working for 3 item case. I've updated the question.